# Mapping with doctrine 2

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, mapping

I have questions which are represented like this in my SQL database :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `t_question` (
  `id_question` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `heading_key` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_question`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Because I want my questions to be multilanguage, I link their keys to another table (t_lang_data) which stores strings for several uses (questions, articles and so on).

My t_lang_data has the folowing structure :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `t_lang_data` (
  `id_lang_data` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `key` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `lang_iso` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `text` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_lang_data`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

So for example I could have this question :

> id_question = 1 ; heading_key =
>   heading_quest_1

And these lang_data entries :

> id_lang_data = 1 ; key =
>   heading_quest_1 ; lang_iso = en_UK ;
>   text = "Heading for question 1"
>   id_lang_data = 2 ; key =
>   heading_quest_1 ; lang_iso = fr ; text
>   = "Titre de la question 1"

I need to map these relations for Doctrine 2 but I do not know what to do.
I have tried a [many-to-one](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-one-unidirectional) and a [one-to-many](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional) approch but it does not work.

Do someone has an idea please ?
Thanks

**EDIT** : I realize that it is even more difficult than what I thought. Indeed, my t_lang_data table can store strings for many tables such as t_questions, t_articles and so on. But in the mapping it seems that we can map only two tables together.

So how could I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You indeed have one of the most common translation issue with databases.

If you want to have an efficient translation behavior without reinventing the wheel, you should use this library : https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions.

It has been recommended by the doctrine2 team and work perfectly well for me. The documentation dedicated to the translation behavior is here : https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions.

Also if you are using symfony2, the dedicated bundle is here : http:// github.com/stof/DoctrineExtensionsBundle

Moreover the translation behavior works just like your, by using a table dedicated to translated string storage referencing the original type and id.

Comment: Thanks ;)
But appearently I cannot add several strings at one time. We have to flush before adding a string in another language.
For example I cannot do that : 
$a = new Article();
$a->setHeading("My English heading");
$a->changeLocale("fr");
$a->setHeading("Mon libellé français");
$a-flush();

Comment: Ok, so all I can suggest you is to code your own behavior. For that you can take ideas from the DoctrineExtensions. So you'll need a table with a class, field and id columns, and to build a custom request to retrieve all your translated fields.